# Conditional Formatting with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have an ASP.NET MVC app that uses Razor in the views. In my view, I have the following:

```
<table style="width:100%;">
 ...
</table>
```

I want to say, `if (items.Count == 0)`, then the background color of the table should be orange. However, `if (items.Count > 0)`, I want the background color of the table to be gray. How do I do this with Razor?

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just to give one more option, you can set color at page begining.

```
@{
    var color = items.Any() ? "#CCC" : "#FF0";
}
```

And at your table tag

```
<table style="color:@color"></table>
```

Comment: Tks man! I am a [KISS Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) adopter. :)

Answer (score 5):

CSS:

```
.table {
    background-color: grey;
}
.table.empty {
    background-color: orange;
}
```

Razor:

```
<table class="table @(items.Count == 0 ? "empty" : null)">
```

This will render as either `<table class="table">` or `<table class="table empty">`.

In general, these are the little rules for how core values (`null`, `""`, `true`, `false`) render inside an HTML attribute in Razor:

```
Razor                    Rendered HTML
----------------------------------------
<abc xyz="s @(null) t">  <abcxyz="s t">
<abc xyz="@(null)">      <abc>
<abc xyz="@("")">        <abc xyz="">
<abc xyz="@(true)">      <abc xyz="xyz">
<abc xyz="@(false)">     <abc>
```

Note the difference between `null` and `""` (empty string).

---

As Chris Pratt points out in his comment, if you don't need to support pre-IE 9, you can use the `:empty` pseudo class to get a similar effect without the ternary operator.

CSS:

```
.table {
    background-color: grey;
}
.table:empty {
    background-color: orange;
}
```

Razor:

```
<table class="table">
```

Comment: To cut down on excess code you could state `@(!items.Any() ? "empty" : null)`, which is my preferred method.

Comment: Best answer, though if you can ignore versions of IE less than 9, you could actually just use `.table:empty` as your selector and then you don't even need the Razor ternary to apply a class. IE9+ and every other browser on the planet supports the `:empty` pseudo-class.

Comment: @Damian I skipped that because I didn't want to have to explain that `System.Linq` needs to be in the set of namespaces you include in all cshtml files. (Or included with `@using` at the top of the cshtml.)

Comment: @ChrisPratt I completely agree.

Comment: @Timothy Shields Not necessaryily, I'm assuming he is passing in a `IEnumerable<T>` to view. If his web.config is set up correctly it will automatically pick up that 'LINQ' is a valid argument to use when utilising a collection.

Comment: @Damian Right, I'm referring to the "If his web.config is set up correctly." Sometimes it isn't and I wanted to keep the solution to the asker's problem isolated. :)

Comment: @TimothyShields Fair enough.

Answer (score 0):

you can use ternary operator:

```
<table style='width:100%; @(items.Count > 0 ? "background-color: grey;" : "background-color: orange;" )'>
 ...
</table>
```